# .NET Winform - No images and default font (resources) during the run time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm using the .NET UI framework MetroModernUI, but I get the user interface like the picture below :

- No images are showing in the run time
- Font have been replaced by the default font, the color as well

Others infos:

- The custom font comes from Metro Modern UI
- All images are embedded in the app, some are fetched using an image fetcher function, others are initialized with their default picture.
- This issue appears on Windows 10.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23088305/39079490-e5530f5e-44e9-11e8-8d47-9b63939c3cfd.png

Does someone has any clue what can affect the app like this ?

Metro Modern UI link : https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,

I found out that this framework *MetroModernUI* **does not support Windows 10 high contrast theme** when activated

Setting available in :

`Setings > Personalization > Colors > Related Settings (High Contrast settings) > Choose a theme`

When this setting is off, the app render well.

Edit: If someone find a way to support this feature without removing the framework, I will like to know how